# Assigning value in constructor to the fields, still not able to set the value and getting null pointer exception when trying to access the value

Tags: c#, constructor

StockBrokerManager.cs

```
using StockBroker.Models;

namespace StockBroker.Managers
{
    public class StockBrokerManager
    {
        OrderValidator validator;
        ExchangeConnector exchangeConnector;

        public StockBrokerManager(OrderValidator validator, ExchangeConnector exchangeConnector)
        {
            validator = validatorA;
            exchangeConnector = exchangeConnectorA;
        }

        public void ExecuteBuyOrder(User user, StockOrder order)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Started executing buy order with {order.OrderId}");
                if (!validator.ValidateBuyOrderRequest(user, order))
                {
                    order.OrderStatus = OrderStatus.RequestInvalid;
                    return;
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"Successfully completed execution of {order.OrderId}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error executing order. Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }


}
```

Program.cs

```
StockBrokerManager stockBrokerManager = new StockBrokerManager(new OrderValidator(), new ExchangeConnector());

stockBrokerManager.ExecuteBuyOrder(user, stockOrder)
```

The above code gives null pointer exception, saying inputValidator is NULL, even though I have set the value of input validator

Changing the variable names in constructor of stockBrokerManager does not give exception.

```
        public StockBrokerManager(OrderValidator validator, ExchangeConnector exchangeConnector)
        {
            validator = validatorA;
            exchangeConnector = exchangeConnectorA;
        }
```

Comment: What are `validatorA` and `exchangeConnectorA`?  Where are those even defined?  It's not clear to me what you're trying to describe.

Comment: If your constructor arguments and fields have the same name, you need to preface the field with `this.`.  I.e. `this.validator = validator;` and `this.exchangeConnector = exchangeConnector;`  Otherwise you just end up assigning the value of the constructor parameter to itself.   See [How do you name constructor argument and member variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/665934).  In fact that may be a duplicate, agree?

Comment: See also the C# language spec [7.7.2.2 Hiding through nesting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#7722-hiding-through-nesting): *Name hiding through nesting can occur as a result of nesting namespaces or types within namespaces, as a result of nesting types within classes or structs, and as a result of **parameter**, local variable, and local constant declarations.*  Your constructor parameters hide the same-named fields.