# how do is this the correct way of writing this <class name> <object name > = new constructor name?

Tags: java

can some one please help me am having a compilation error with the last part of this code 
its saying create constructor please help

```
public class Officer {

     public static void main(String args[]) {

         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.print("Enter the name of the Soldier: ");

         String name = input.nextLine();

         System.out.print("Enter the sex of the Soldier: ");

         String sex = input.nextLine();

         System.out.print("Enter the Age of the Soldier: ");

         String age = input.nextLine();

         Soldier soldier = new Soldier(name, sex, age);
    }
}
```

```
package officer; 

public class Soldier { 

    private String soldierName; 
    private int soldierAge; 
    private char soldierSex; 

    public void Soldier( String name, char sex, int age) { 
         soldierName = name; 
         soldierSex = sex; 
         soldierAge = age; 
    } 

    public String getSoldierName() { 
        return soldierName; 
    } 
    public char getSoldierSex() { 
         return soldierSex; 
    } 
    public int getSoldierAge() { 
        return soldierAge; 
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have a constructor to match `Soldier(name,sex,age)`?

Comment: print stackTrace here!!!!!

Comment: Issue might be, There is no any constructor at all in Soldier class, or different type argument in constructor like `Soldier (String name, String sex, int age)`

Comment: yes to my other class called soldier i have a constructor called public void Soldier( String name, char sex, int age)

Comment: here is the other class called soldier                              package officer;
public class Soldier
{
  private String soldierName;
  private int soldierAge;
  private char soldierSex;

  public void Soldier( String name, char sex, int age)
     {
        soldierName = name;
        soldierSex = sex;
        soldierAge = age;
     }
     public String getSoldierName()
     {
        return soldierName;
     }
     public char getSoldierSex()
     {
        return soldierSex;
     }
     public int getSoldierAge()
     {
        return soldierAge;
     }}

Comment: Constructors have no "return value". Look here for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788312/why-do-constructors-not-return-values

Answer (score 3):

The class `Soldier` needs to define a matching constructor

```
public Soldier (String name, String sex, String age) {
    // do stuff
}
```

This is the method that what be executed, when you call `new Soldier(name, sex, age)`

Answer (score 0):

It ok, except:

- sex should be en enum type
- age should be an integer (or float) type
- **you should validate user input**

An `SEX` enum:

```
public enum SEX {
    MALE, FEMALE
}
```

A constructor:

```
public Soldier (String name, SEX sex, int age) {

}
```

Comment: yeah i have that in my other class called soldier is it okay

Answer (score 0):

You would need something like:

```
public class Soldier {

    public Soldier(String name, String sex, int age) {

    }
}
```

edit: with the new info provided you should delete the `void` in the `public void Soldier` since `void` would mean `public void Soldier` is a method of `class Soldier` while it's supposed to be the constructor.

Comment: please NO single chars as parameternames ;)

Comment: Because? I always do it like this.

Comment: The names of variables should have a good name for it, that you know what the variable is and where it stands for. :)

Comment: If i would declare `String name;` for example and then write in the constructor: `name = n; `. I don't see the problem in that. Else i would get `this.name = name;` which i find confusing.

Comment: Example: If someone use your constructor and see the parameters: Soldier(String n, String s, int a), its not clear what you mean with it, he must open and read the single comments for the parameters / documentation. Topic for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991757/best-practice-for-parameter-naming-in-java-constructors-and-simple-setters

Comment: You are right. Probably `soldierName = name;` would be the way to go. More typing tho. :)