# How do I use the same variable name of a local variable and a constructor parameter in the same class?

Tags: java

So I was wondering if I could declare an instance field(ex. str1) and a parameter with the same name.
Basicly, I ran something akin to

```
 private String str1;
 private String str2;
 StringTester str= new StringTester(String str1, String str2)
 {
    str1=str1;
    str2=str2;
 }
```

The tester class printed out null when I asked for str1. Was I supposed to use "this" or is that not applicable at all?
(I know this is bad programming convention, but I was just wondering.

Comment: use `this`. i.e., `this.str1 = str1;`

Comment: You're confusing the declaration of a constructor, and the call of a constructor. Re-read your introductory Java book for the syntax of a constructor. And no, this isn't bad practice at all. It's even conventional to name them the same way.

Comment: OK, this **has** to be a duplicate question, but I can't find the dup. Someone anyone, please help me close this question before we get a million unnecessary answers.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991757/best-practice-for-parameter-naming-in-java-constructors-and-simple-setters ?

Comment: @JBNizet: looks good, thanks! I love this site, but I sometimes have a devil of a time finding duplicates.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I use google to find them. It's better at searching than StackOverflow.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I searched for duplicates before asking, but I didnt see that. Sorry about that.

Comment: The question title says this is for a local variable yet the answers and duplicate reference a class variable. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Deco Yeah, the "dup" is kinda different. I didn't really check it out because I just assumed Hovercraft was right. Oh well, it's too late to care now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be

```
public class StringTester{
  private String str1;
  private String str2;

  StringTester(String str1, String str2)
  {
     this.str1 = str1;
     this.str2 = str2;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple

```
 this.str1 = str1;
 this.str2 = str2;
```

now call this.str1 , this.str2 anywhere